# Getting incorrect syntax error '?' when trying to run the below two lines

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have an incremental job that keeps only 2 years of data. We have nightly and hourly jobs to get data from the source (using OLE DB Source component).

These two lines were taken from one of the source queries for the datasets.

```
DECLARE @LastIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = ?
DECLARE @CurrentTrackDBVersionID BIGINT = ?
```

These two lines are throwing error during execution, how can I make these two lines work?

The error returned is

```
OLEDB source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80040E14
```

Comment: We have an incremental job that keeps only 2 years of data. We have nightly and hourly jobs to get data from  the source (SSMS) to SSIS. these two lines were taken from one of the source queries for the datasets. And it is built as the following path (Extractfile\IncrementalLoad\dataset\rowextractor\sourceLoop\sourceQuery) the above two lines that i am getting the syntax error on are located all the way in the sourceQuery at the end .

Comment: it is an OLE DB source

Comment: i am not sure if that question mark is being used as a parameter

Comment: the error message is " sourceQuery: Error: OLEDB source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80040E14

Comment: Is that the **only** error message you see or are there loads? I've not worked with SSIS for years but looking at the example here it seems it may well be much more verbose with potentially more useful information in other messages https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/82730536-2693-462a-b748-32314901bff4/ssis-error-code-dtseoledberror?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: yes only error is the above error

Answer (score 0):

try below

Your Parameter:

```
DECLARE @LastIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = ?  
DECLARE @CurrentTrackDBVersionID BIGINT = ?
```

Updated Parameter:

```
DECLARE @LastIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = null  
DECLARE @CurrentTrackDBVersionID BIGINT = null
```

Comment: will this break the logic ?